# ngClass with hover Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Let's say i have this :

```
 <div 
     class="italic" 
     ng-class="{red: hover}" 
     ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
     ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
         Test 1 2 3.
    </div>
     <div 
     class="italic" 
     ng-class="{red: hover}" 
     ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
     ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
         Test 1 2 3.
    </div>
```

i want to change color with red class when user hover the div . but now when hovering both div get red .
[**[Fiddle][1](http://jsfiddle.net/pthfV/236/)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pthfV/236/) for playing with Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use directive

```
.directive('hoverClass', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            hoverClass: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('mouseenter', function() {
                element.addClass(scope.hoverClass);
            });
            element.on('mouseleave', function() {
                element.removeClass(scope.hoverClass);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And add this html

```
<div class="italic" hover-class="red" >
     Test 1 2 3.
</div>
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/pthfV/238/

Comment: thx man but i'm sure there is a way without writing directive

Comment: italic:hover{ color: red } in CSS :)

Comment: ng-class="{red: hover2}" 
     ng-mouseenter="hover2 = true"
     ng-mouseleave="hover2 = false"> -Just give the other div a unique value. Even though the directive is the DRY and angular way to go about this. This would be the easy route.

Comment: i can't add a unique value to this, because there is a lot of div like this .

Comment: @Artemkh what u did in directive is exactly mean what i did in html, why is it different in action ?

Comment: Are these divs being rendered through an ng-repeat?

Comment: Because you are using $scope.hover for adding class to all divs and when you are hovering on element it's changed $scope.hover to 'true' and all divs changing class to red. When i use directive it's adds class only for element which you are hover. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: you're great. totally understand . thx for sharing your time with me :)

Comment: But if you are really don't want to use directive try this code http://jsfiddle.net/src5k0bf/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="italic" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-mouseover="hoverSelect($index)" 
ng-mouseleave="hoverDeselect($index)" ng-class="{red: $index == {{active}}}">


Controller:
$scope.hoverSelect = function(index) {
     $scope.active = index;
     }

$scope.hoverDeselect = function(index) {
     $scope.active = '';
     }
```

Comment: The ng-repeat gives you access to the current indexed item through $index, which is really useful. Here we're using that as our parameter to the functions that get called on mouseleave and mouseover

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a directive or function for this. You just need a separate variable for each div. This may be `hover1` vs `hover2`, `hovers.div1` vs `hovers.div2`, or even `hover[0]` vs `hover[1]`. If both divs act based on the same variable, the action will always occur to both divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/pthfV/841/